# Simulating a vector ODE using python GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to learn how to use the [GEKKO](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO) python package. As a first step, I would like to simulate a simple vector ODE: dx/dt = A*x, where A is a matrix and x is a vector. All the ODE examples I have seen for GEKKO have been for scalar ODEs and the array example from the online [documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) doesn't show how to incorporate the .dt() method when declaring an Equation. I know that when declaring equations, lists can be used, so I thought something like this would be the way to go:

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m=GEKKO()
m.time=np.linspace(0.,1.,10)
N=5
A=np.ones([N,N])
x=np.ones(N)
x=m.Var(value=x)
A=m.Param(value=A)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        m.Equation(x[i].dt() += A[i][j] * x[j])

m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve()
```

but this code will fail for two reasons: 1) += isn't a valid comparison for the Equation method, and 2) python complains that x[i].dt() is not a valid attribute of x[i] (which is a np.float64). So how would I simulate this ODE in GEKKO, if it is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to simulate the model:

**dx/dt = A x**

is to declare `x` as a Array and use `np.dot()` to do the matrix multiplication with each row of `A`.

[image: State Space Simulation]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m=GEKKO()
m.time=np.linspace(0.,1.,10)
N=5
A=np.ones((N,N))
ic = array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
x=m.Array(m.Var,N,value=0.) #initialize to zero
for i in range(N):
    x[i].value = ic[i] #set to some initial condition
m.Equations([x[i].dt()==np.dot(A[i,:],x) for i in range(N)])
m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(N):
    plt.plot(m.time,x[i].value)
plt.show()
```

Another way is with a [state space object in Gekko](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/LinearStateSpace)

**dx/dt = A x + B u**

**y = C x + D u**

with *B*=0, *C*=0, and *D*=0. Both methods give the same result.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m=GEKKO()
m.time=np.linspace(0.,1.,10)
N=5
A=np.ones((N,N))
B=np.zeros((N,1))
C=np.zeros((1,N))
x,y,u = m.state_space(A,B,C,D=None)
for i in range(N):
    x[i].value=1
m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(N):
    plt.plot(m.time,x[i].value)
plt.show()
```